# Find MLE by combining two different experiments

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

I am trying to solve the following problem on an assignment.

> Anna has two dice. Die $F$ is fair: it rolls $1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Die $D$ is dodgy: Anna suspects that it may be rolling even and odd numbers with unequal probabilities. To investigate, Anna rolls die $D$ 40 times; 32 of these rolls result in odd numbers.
>
> Let $q$ be the probability of rolling an odd number on die $D$.
>
> The next day, Anna's friend Bob borrows Anna's dice and tries a different experiment. He rolls dice $D$ and $F$ together, multiplies the two resulting numbers, and notes whether the product is even or odd. After repeating this procedure 50 times, he finds that the product was odd on 16 occasions.
>
> Find the maximum likelihood estimate of $q$ based on the two experiments combined.

The number of odd numbers that Anna records $X_A$ is clearly distributed as

$X_A \sim Bin(40,q)$

For Bob, the probability of recording an odd result is

$\mathbb P(\textrm{product is odd}) = \mathbb P(D\textrm{ is odd}) \mathbb P(F\textrm{ is odd}) = 0.5q$

since we know that die $F$ is fair. Therefore the number of odd numbers he records $X_B$ should be distributed

$X_B \sim Bin(50,0.5q)$

Finally, I understand that the MLE $\hat{q}$ should satisfy

$\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}q} \mathbb L(q; X_A = 32)\mathbb L(0.5q; X_B = 16) = 0$

Is this correct? Taking the derivative of the function above and solving for $\hat{q}$ seems to be much too complicated. Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood function is
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(q) &= {40 \choose 32} q^{32}(1-q)^{40-32} {50 \choose 16} (0.5q)^{16}(1-0.5q)^{50-16} \\
&=  {40 \choose 32} {50 \choose 16} 0.5^{16}q^{32+16}(1-q)^{40-32}(1-0.5q)^{50-16} .
\end{align*}$$

Since the log function is a monotonic transformation, the maximizer of the log likelihood function will be the maximizer of the likelihood function. The log likelihood function is,
$$\begin{align*}
\log\mathcal{L}(q) = \log\left({40 \choose 32} {50 \choose 16} 0.5^{16}\right) + (32+16)\log(q) + (40-32)\log(1-q)+(50-16)\log(1-0.5q)
\end{align*}$$.

The derivative with respect to $q$ is,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\log\mathcal{L}(q) = (32+16)\frac{1}{\log(q)} + (40-32)\frac{1}{(1-q)}(-1)+(50-16)\frac{1}{(1-0.5q)}(-0.5)
\end{align*}$$.

Solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\log\mathcal{L}(q)=0$ for $q$, and solutions for $q$ will be $q \in \left\{\frac{97-\sqrt{769}}{90}, \frac{97+\sqrt{769}}{90} \right\}$. Discard the solution that is not between 0 and 1, so
$$\hat{q}_{MLE} = \frac{97-\sqrt{769}}{90} \approx 0.77.$$